# ionic3--how can I show tabs in sub page when I set app config 'tabsHideOnSubPages=true'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my app.module.ts:

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
  backButtonIcon: 'ios-arrow-back' ,
  backButtonText: '',
  pageTransition: 'md-transition',
  activator: 'ripple',
  mode: 'md',
  tabsHideOnSubPages: true
})
```

then, my all sub page will show without tabs,but now, I need show tabs in a special sub page.

I try to set config before I push the sub page like this:

```
import { NavController, Config } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(
  public navCtrl: NavController,
  public config: Config
) {
  ......
}

ionViewDidEnter(){
  this.config.set('tabsHideOnSubPages', false)
  this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage)
}
```

but it not work,how can I do?

Comment: someone help me !?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NavController, App, Config } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public app:App,public navCtrl: NavController,
  public config: Config) {}

ionViewDidEnter(){
  this.config.set('tabsHideOnSubPages', false)
  let nav = this.app.getRootNav();
  nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
}
```

You can try this code.

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn`t work for me.
I am very confused that I set config like " this.config.set( ' pageTransition ' , ' md-transition ' )  "  before I push a sub page,it works.But I set 'tabsHideOnSubPages = true' , nothing happen